# No visible @interface for 'RCTBundleURLProvider'

Tags: objective-c, react-native

I am adding a method to `AppDelegate.m` by following the react native 0.68 codepush [doc](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/master/docs/setup-ios.md) which does not provide detail for the change. Here is the `AppDelegate.m` after change:

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CodePush/CodePush.h> /* for rn codepush */
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h> /* for rn codepush */

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, RCTBridgeDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

/* for rn code push */
- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge 
{
  #if DEBUG
    return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];  /*this line throw error */
  #else
    return [CodePush bundleURL];
  #endif
}

@end
```

Now the error is `No visible @interface for 'RCTBundleURLProvider' declares the selector 'jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:fallbackResource:'`.

Comment: Just import the .h files that contains the `RCTBundleURLProvider` declaration (the way you imported `#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>`).

Comment: #Import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>, and another error throws: `No visible @interface for 'RCTBundleURLProvider' declares the selector 'jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:fallbackResource:'`, Not sure what is still missing.

Comment: That's weird, I can see `RCTBundleURLProvider` has `jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:fallbackResource:`: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/React/Base/RCTBundleURLProvider.h Did you try to update the dependency of react-native? Could it be that you use an older version that doesn't have this method?

Answer (score 1):

Might be late here :)

After some research, I found out that ***jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:fallbackResource:*** no longer exists on *RCTBundleURLProvider.*

**Here's the Fix:**

**Replace**

```
return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
```

**with**

```
return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
```

Re-Build the app and you are good to go.